# Searching a comparison database for 2 objects of the same type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a database, that has 2 objects of the same type, for instance a "Car".

Then I have another database that is a "CompareCars" that has a car1 and a car2 variables that I want to search for the 2 Car objects that could be in either car1 and car2 position. Meaning it could come out as either car1: Car1, car2: Car2 OR car1: Car2, car2: Car1.

I assume it's something along the lines of...

```
compare_car = CompareCar.where(car1_id: @car1, car2_id: @car2)
compare_car = CompareCar.where(car1_id: @car2, car2_id: @car1)
```

But I am trying to get it into one line where it would be not trying to overwrite said lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, if I understand your problem correctly...

```
compare_car = CompareCar.where(car1_id: [ @car1 , @car2 ] , car2_id: [ @car1 , @car2 ])
```

Comment: I also got it to work with:
`compare_car = CompareCar.where(car1_id: @car1, car2_id: @car2) | CompareCar.where(car1_id: @car2, car2_id: @car1)`